# STM32 SPI Slow Compute

Tags: embedded, stm32, spi

I'm using a STM32F4 and its SPI to talk to a 74HC595 like in this tutorial. Difference is for starters I'm using the non-DMA version for simplicity. I used STMCubeMX to configure SPI and GPIO

Issue is: I'm not getting the latch PIN, that I set to PA8 to toggle during transmission fast enough.

[image]

The code I'm using:

```
        spiTxBuf[0] = 0b00000010;

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spiTxBuf, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
//        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);

        HAL_Delay(1);
```

Things I tried:

1. Set the Maxium Output Speed of the Pin PA8 to Very Fast
   [image]
2. Wait for the SPI to be done (see commented line above)
3. Use DMA for the SPI as in here, that made it actually slower.

How do i get that to toggle faster? Should i create and interrupt for when the SPI is done and set the latch there?

Comment: Which controller is that, on what clock frequency? What is the requirement, the acceptable delays before/after?

Comment: is @berendi wrote in his answer if you use HAL be prepared those functions to be slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do i get that to toggle faster?

**If possible, use the hardware NSS pin**

*Some* STM32 controllers can toggle their `NSS` pin automatically, with a configurable delay after transmission. Check the Reference Manual, if yours is one of these, reconnect the latch pin of the shifter to the `SPIx_NSS` pin on the MCU.

**Don't use HAL**

HAL is quite slow and overcomplicated for anything with tight timing requirements. Don't use it.

Just implement the SPI transmit procedure in the Reference Manual.

```
SPI->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE; // this is required only once
GPIOA->BSRR = 1 << (8 + 16);
*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI->DR = 0b00000010;
while((SPI->SR & (SPI_SR_TXE | SPI_SR_BSY)) != SPI_SR_TXE)
    ;
GPIOA->BSRR = 1 << 8;
```

Comment: Replace `SPI` with the actual SPI controller, e.g. `SPI1` or `SPI2` or whichever you actually use.

Comment: yeah figured that out :) Cant find the SPI_SR_SPE flag though, google yields nothing as well. What does it do?

Comment: @Julian Sorry, it was a typo. Code is fixed now.

Comment: Hmm, doesnt work with this code:
SPI1->SR |= SPI_CR1_SPE; // this is required only once
        GPIOA->BSRR = 1 << (8 + 16);
        *(volatile uint8_t *)SPI1->DR = 0b00000010;
        while((SPI1->SR & (SPI_SR_TXE | SPI_SR_BSY)) != SPI_SR_TXE);
        GPIOA->BSRR = 1 << 8;

Comment: @Julian take a close look at the first line

Comment: yeah i'm executing that before the while loop :) Adding the 1 to  CR1 didn't help either.

Comment: That did it! Last question: how would I go about sending multiple bytes, in a for loop?

Comment: Wait for `((SPI->SR & SPI_SR_TXE) != 0)` before sending each byte.

Comment: Hmm that doesnt seem to work. while((SPI1->SR & (SPI_SR_TXE | SPI_SR_BSY)) != SPI_SR_TXE); in the for loop works but costs time between each byte. Your snippet only sends 2 bytes out of 5.

Comment: The last check is only required after sending the last byte, i.e. it's the prerequisite of raising the latch signal. Read the *Data transmission and reception procedures* section in the Reference Manual.

Answer (score 5):

So after some input I figured out a solution where I redefined the HAL functions and  basically threw everything out that was slow:

```
void HAL_GPIO_WritePin_Fast(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PinState PinState)
{

    if(PinState != GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    {
        GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;
    }
    else
    {
        GPIOx->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_Pin << 16U;
    }
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit_fast(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
//    uint32_t tickstart = 0U;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef errorcode = HAL_OK;

    /* Check Direction parameter */

    /* Process Locked */
    __HAL_LOCK(hspi);

    /* Init tickstart for timeout management*/
//    tickstart = HAL_GetTick();

//    if(hspi->State != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)
//    {
//        errorcode = HAL_BUSY;
//        goto error;
//    }
//
//    if((pData == NULL ) || (Size == 0))
//    {
//        errorcode = HAL_ERROR;
//        goto error;
//    }

    /* Set the transaction information */
    hspi->State       = HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_TX;
    hspi->ErrorCode   = HAL_SPI_ERROR_NONE;
    hspi->pTxBuffPtr  = (uint8_t *)pData;
    hspi->TxXferSize  = Size;
    hspi->TxXferCount = Size;

    /*Init field not used in handle to zero */
    hspi->pRxBuffPtr  = (uint8_t *)NULL;
    hspi->RxXferSize  = 0U;
    hspi->RxXferCount = 0U;
    hspi->TxISR       = NULL;
    hspi->RxISR       = NULL;

    /* Configure communication direction : 1Line */
    if(hspi->Init.Direction == SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE)
    {
        SPI_1LINE_TX(hspi);
    }

#if (USE_SPI_CRC != 0U)
    /* Reset CRC Calculation */
  if(hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE)
  {
    SPI_RESET_CRC(hspi);
  }
#endif /* USE_SPI_CRC */

    /* Check if the SPI is already enabled */
    if((hspi->Instance->CR1 & SPI_CR1_SPE) != SPI_CR1_SPE)
    {
        /* Enable SPI peripheral */
        __HAL_SPI_ENABLE(hspi);
    }

    /* Transmit data in 16 Bit mode */
    if(hspi->Init.DataSize == SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT)
    {
        if((hspi->Init.Mode == SPI_MODE_SLAVE) || (hspi->TxXferCount == 0x01))
        {
            hspi->Instance->DR = *((uint16_t *)pData);
            pData += sizeof(uint16_t);
            hspi->TxXferCount--;
        }
        /* Transmit data in 16 Bit mode */
        while (hspi->TxXferCount > 0U)
        {
            /* Wait until TXE flag is set to send data */
            if(__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE))
            {
                hspi->Instance->DR = *((uint16_t *)pData);
                pData += sizeof(uint16_t);
                hspi->TxXferCount--;
            }
            else
            {
//                /* Timeout management */
//                if((Timeout == 0U) || ((Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY) && ((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) >=  Timeout)))
//                {
//                    errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
//                    goto error;
//                }
            }
        }
    }
        /* Transmit data in 8 Bit mode */
    else
    {
        if((hspi->Init.Mode == SPI_MODE_SLAVE)|| (hspi->TxXferCount == 0x01))
        {
            *((__IO uint8_t*)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*pData);
            pData += sizeof(uint8_t);
            hspi->TxXferCount--;
        }
        while (hspi->TxXferCount > 0U)
        {
            /* Wait until TXE flag is set to send data */
            if(__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE))
            {
                *((__IO uint8_t*)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*pData);
                pData += sizeof(uint8_t);
                hspi->TxXferCount--;
            }
            else
            {
//                /* Timeout management */
//                if((Timeout == 0U) || ((Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY) && ((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) >=  Timeout)))
//                {
//                    errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
//                    goto error;
//                }
            }
        }
    }





    /* Clear overrun flag in 2 Lines communication mode because received is not read */
    if(hspi->Init.Direction == SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES)
    {
        __HAL_SPI_CLEAR_OVRFLAG(hspi);
    }
#if (USE_SPI_CRC != 0U)
    /* Enable CRC Transmission */
  if(hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE)
  {
     SET_BIT(hspi->Instance->CR1, SPI_CR1_CRCNEXT);
  }
#endif /* USE_SPI_CRC */

    if(hspi->ErrorCode != HAL_SPI_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        errorcode = HAL_ERROR;
    }

    error:
    hspi->State = HAL_SPI_STATE_READY;
    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hspi);
    return errorcode;
}
```

That's definitely an option but probably not the most elegant :) It sped up the time dramatically though:

[image]

Edit:
berendis solution is even faster:

[image]

Heres the code for multiple bytes:

```
spiTxBuf[0] = 0b00000110;
spiTxBuf[1] = 0b00000111;
spiTxBuf[2] = 0b00000111;
spiTxBuf[3] = 0b00000111;
spiTxBuf[4] = 0b00000111;

GPIOA->BSRR = 1 << (8 + 16);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = spiTxBuf[i];
    while ((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE) == RESET);

}

while((SPI1->SR & (SPI_SR_TXE | SPI_SR_BSY)) != SPI_SR_TXE);
GPIOA->BSRR = 1 << 8;
HAL_Delay(100);
```

Comment: This is some serious bloatware... all you should need to do for simplex communication is: setup SPI including baudrate and clock, once. Set /SS pin. Start of loop. Write to data register. Wait for status flag. End of loop. Clear /SS pin.

Comment: I've bookmarked this Q&A now because it shows *exactly* how inefficient HAL is. Thanks for the scope shots:)

Comment: youre welcome, if I get your code to run, ill make a third :)

Comment: Another typo fixed in it (missing `&`)

Comment: Yup, that worked, you can steal that last screenshot for your answer :)