# ADC on NUCLEO- STM32F401RE board does not work beyond 10kHz of input signal

Tags: stm32, adc, nucleo

[image: Plot of 60-80kHz using continuous conversion- DMA][image: Edit 1:Image of 10kHz to 50kHz input signal using continuous conversion]I am using the ADC on NUCLEO- STM32F401RE board. I have programmed the ADC using interrupts store about 10,000 values in an array and read them using a .ini file. The code does not work beyond 10kHz of input signal. ADC is of 12 bit resolution with 3 sampling cycles ; ADC clock frequency is 21Khz. Below is my code and plot of values for input frequency range of 1- 200Khz sine wave. The input voltage is 1.3V. What am I missing?

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" 
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);

uint32_t adc_data[10000];
uint32_t i=0;
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{   if (i<10000) {
adc_data[i]= HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    i++;
HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
}
    else {
    HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&hadc1);
}
}

int main(void)
{
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);

while (1)
  {

  }

}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);
  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                          |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of     conversion) 
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and              its sample time. 
   */
   sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
   sConfig.Rank = 1;
   sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
   if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
   {
     Error_Handler();
   }
 }

 static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
 { 
   /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
   __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

 }

 void Error_Handler(void)
 {

 }

 #ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

[plot of values for input frequency range of 1- 200Khz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSodR.jpg)

Comment: *ADC clock frequency is 21Khz* Did you mean 21 **MHz**?

Comment: @berendi Yes, 21MHz. My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the 21 kHz is a typo, and the ADC is running on APB2/4 = 21 MHz. Sampling time is 3 cycles, conversion time at 12 bits resolution is 12 cycles, so the **sampling frequency of the ADC is = 1.4 MHz** (`21/(12+3)`). When the core is running at 84 MHz, that's one sample every 60 core cycles.

**60 cycles are barely enough to even start executing an interrupt handler**, with flash wait states taken into account.

Looking at the plot you've attached it looks like the **actual sampling frequency is 300 kHz** (there are 30 samples in a full cycle of the 10 kHz signal), that's 3.33 µs, or 25200 clock cycles. Considering the [ridiculous amount of overhead in HAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440516/stm32-spi-slow-compute), it seems realistic.

Your code makes a single conversion with an interrupt triggered when it's complete, then reads and stores the value, and only then instructs the ADC to start the next conversion, introducing a variable delay that depends on a couple of hard to predict factors.

### Use Continuous Conversion

The ADC is able to restart the coversion (or the sequence if there is one), either immediately after finishing the last one, or triggered by a timer, see the description of `EXTSEL`, `EXTEN`, `SCAN` and `CONT` bits of the control registers in the Reference Manual. It can even trigger a DMA transfer after each conversion, so you can set up a DMA channel to store the readings into a buffer. This would guarantee even sampling intervals even at the highest possible sampling frequency.

Comment: Hi @berendi, Thank you for your inputs.I used DMA continuous conversion and stored the values for 12 bits ADC with ADC clock freq= 21 Mhz. Here is a snippet of my code  
`uint32_t adc_data[10000];
uint32_t i=0;
 while (1)
  {
if (i<10000) {
 HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1,adc_data,10000);
   i++;
  }
 else { HAL_ADC_Stop_DMA(&hadc1);
}
 }
}`


There is an improvement and works until 50kHz, but is distorted beyond that. Is this due to HAL overhead? How do I get the ADC to work for input frequencies between 100kHz-250kHz.

Comment: Edit :Please find attached the plots(10-50kHz , 60-80kHz) for results obtained from DMA continuous conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Please habe a look at [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)

In short:
With a ADC frequency of 21kHz you could sample the input with 7kHz and that means your 
highest possible signal frequency is at ~3.5kHz.

Comment: The ADC throughput is 2 MSPS. The ADC clock frequency is 21MHz. Apologies for the mistake!