# One bit shift in SPI communication on STM32H7

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm working on SPI communication between two Nucleo-H743ZI boards.
I'm using ST's HAL, and the SPI polling API HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive.

It's working fine until a bandwith of 12Mbits/s (SPI kernel clock at 200Mhz and prescaler 16, the CPU is always at 400Mhz) but fails above (smaller prescaler).

I want to understand since 24 or 48 Mbits/s doesn't seem much even in polling with a poor quality software.

With prescaler set to 8, I don't have SPI error like overrun or other (I checked directly in registers), however the data are not correct. looking closer to the data, I've noticed that there is only a shift of one bit.

More precisely I should receive (in hexa ): 0x30 0x31 0x32 ...
And I receive 0x18 0x18 0x99...

In binary:

- expected 0011 0000 0011 0001 0011 0010...
- received 0001 1000 0001 1000 1001 1001...

If I shift the received bitstream to the left I get exactly the right result.

Does it ring something to you ? Could it be due to a bad configuration ?

Obviously master and slave have the same configuration regarding phase and polarity (and everything else since the source code is mostly identical).

Comment: Such a bit shift could indicate that you the SPI master or slave is not operating in the correct SPI mode. The SPI mode defines clock polarity and phase. If they aren't matching between slave and master, you can get data shifted by one bit.

Comment: You're right but as I've written, the SPI initialisation code is the same for slave and master. I just double checked, Phase and polarity are the same for both. And it's working anyway at slower frequencies.

Comment: How could we guess if you don't **show the code**? What are the relevant `GPIO` register values, in particular `OTYPER`, `OSPEEDR`, `PUPDR` *at the time of the transmission*?

Comment: Does the master or the slave have trouble receiving data? And it would probably be helpful if you could capture the signals with an oscilloscope and add a screenshot to the question. The problem could be at the hardware level.

Comment: @codo Good remark. Actually the slave receives correctly, the error is only at master side.Communication is full duplex. I agree about the benefit of a scope capture but I don't have one. I will try to set the slave in DMA mode, in case it is not fast enough to receive and send.

Comment: @berendi for the SPI GPIO (SCK, MISO and MOSI) they are in alternate function mode, and  their OTYPER is 0 (output push pull) , PUPDR is 0 (no pull up or pull down) and OSPEED is also 0 (low speed). The latter might be the issue ?

Comment: @berendi, I confirmed that the GPIO speed was set to "low" in STMicro's code and increasing the GPIO speed fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check the *Output timing characteristics* table in the datasheet.**

The binary number in the leftmost column is the value that goes in `GPIO->OSPEEDR`. At V<sub>DD</sub>=3.3V (That's what the Nucleo board uses), value `00` would work up to 12 MHz, that's exactly where your signal is starting to break down. Just turn it up to the maximal value, it doesn't hurt. (Well, it might overload something if you toggle lots of pins at once.)

Answer (score 0):

48mbits means 6MB per second. Even if your uC is 400MHz you have only 50 clocks  per byte. It is far not enough. For the higher speeds only DMA is possible definitely not the polling especially using HAL libraries.

48MHz cablewise  is not easy as well.

Comment: Well as far as I understood the SPI can work on 32 bits granularity which means the CPU would have to process less than 2 words per us ie. 2 words in 400 cycles. Doesn't seem impossible.

Comment: Using HAL? Very unlikely

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean don't ever underestimate the [amount of overhead in HAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440516/stm32-spi-slow-compute).

Comment: Why dv by the way?

Comment: For the record I could communicate up to 95Mhz (which is close to the theoretical maximum on this product I think ?) using the HAL HAL_SPI_Transmit on one side and HAL_SPI_Receive on the other side. There were many bugs in the HAL but in terms of performance it's not so bad, at least the software is not the bottleneck. In real fullduplex mode (API HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive), it works only up to 24MHz.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean the communication itself (from the moment when you load the data to the data register does not have anything in common with the HAL. I think you should read more about how this SPI works.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words (once again...). In polling when you exit from function HAL_SPI_Transmit, it means EOT has been set, meaning (to quote the ref manual) "TSIZE number of data have been transmitted on SPI". So it indeed measures the duration of the communication (with the overhead of the function initialisation). For DMA or IT API obvisouly the duration of functions has nothing to do with the duration of the communication itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try enabling the SPI unit before selecting the slave

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).